# jquery selector before-last

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a dynamic list and need to select the before last item.

```
<ul class="album">
    <li id='li-1'></li>
    <!-- ... -->
    <li id='li-8'></li>
    <li id='li-9'></li>
    <li class='drop-placeholder'>drag your favorites here</li>
</ul>

var lastLiId = $(".album li:last").attr("id"); // minus one?
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) with a negative value (`-1` is last) to get `n` from the end, like this:

```
$(".album li").eq(-2).attr("id"); // gets "li-9"
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/nQeC8/).

Comment: @richsage - They do :) "Providing a negative number indicates a position starting from the end of the set, rather than the beginning", make sure you're looking at the `.eq()` docs and not the `:eq()` docs: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 22):

Probably a neater way but how about:

```
var lastLiId = $(".album li:last").prev("li").attr("id");
```