# How can I use the :nth-child() selector starting from the last element, rather than the first?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('ul').find('li:nth-child(2)').css('color', '#f00')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Glen</li>
  <li>Tane</li>
  <li>Ralph</li>
  <li>David</li>
</ul>

<button>Draw it</button>
```

I wanna get element `<li>Ralph</li>` by this way: Providing a negative number indicates a position starting from the end of the set, just like `.eq(-2)`:

`$('ul').find('li:nth-child(-2)').css('color', '#f00')`

Is it possible? If not, is there a way to override `nth-child() function`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery selector before-last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905377/jquery-selector-before-last)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`:nth-last-child(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-last-child).

This is a standards compliant selector, so it also works with `.querySelectorAll` and in your CSS.

```js
$('ul').find('li:nth-last-child(2)').css('color', '#f00')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Glen</li>
  <li>Tane</li>
  <li>Ralph</li>
  <li>David</li>
</ul>

<button>Draw it</button>
```

This will also work if there are multiple `ul` elements. Non-standard selectors like jQuery's `.eq()` will only give you the second to last element out of the entire set.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`:nth-last-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/) selector.  It counts up from the last child, starting from 1 as the last.

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('ul').find('li:nth-last-child(2)').css('color', '#f00')
});
```